# Application crashes when I try to display multiple images with a for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to display multiple random grass tile images across the 1200 pixel width window.  I am using a method called *placeGrass* which takes an image, an x coordinate, a y coordinate, and then displays the object at that given coordinate.  This works correctly if I use my method *getRandomGrass()* (which returns a random grass tile image) and type in each coordinate by hand.  However, when I try and use a method I made called *printGrass()*, the flash application fails to boot up.

Here is my attempt at the printGrass() method.

```
public function printGrass():void
    {
        var grass:Grass = new Grass(play);

        for(var i:int = 0; i < 1200; i + 64)
        {
            grass.placeGrass(grass.getRandomGrass(), i, 800);
        }
    }
```

Where as my manual attempts below work correctly.

```
var test:Grass = new Grass(play);
test.placeGrass(test.getRandomGrass(), 0, 800);
var test2:Grass = new Grass(play);
test2.placeGrass(test2.getRandomGrass(), 64, 800);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the for statement is never terminated because the counter does not increment the i variable.

`for(var i:int = 0; i < 1200; i + 64)`

should read

`for(var i:int = 0; i < 1200; i += 64)`

`i + 64` will just return 64 each time where `i += 64` will increment i each time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, thank you!  Don't know how I missed this because I did indeed have it like that before then I switched it to i++.  I think I made the mistake when switching back from i++ and kept over looking it somehow.

Comment: You should mark this correct if the answer was a solution